# How to synchronize the access to a variable as it changed in multiple classes?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I've a scheduler class and another class a custom http client.

The scheduler is initialized on application start up and does the work in background for example querying a service (url) every 30 seconds and write the data to logs.

The http client is created with the url as well.

The url can change anytime so I need to make sure whenever it is the both log scheduler and http client are reinitialized with new url.

```
public class LogScheduler {
   public log() {
     synchronized(globallock) {
       String url = getUrl();
       //log some activity
     }
   }
}
```

We have another scheduler which is looking for new url every 30 minutes.

```
public class UrlScheduler {
   private volatile String url;
   public void check() {
     String url = service.getNewUrl();
     if(url!=this.url) {
       synchronized(globallock) {
        this.url=url;
        reinitialize http client
       }
     }
   }
   public String getUrl(){
    return url;
   }
}
```

Right now I'm using global lock to make sure the log scheduler sees the value as soon it is changed by url scheduler. I really don't like the idea of using global lock as it breaks encapsulation along with other issues.

How could I change my set up to to reinitialize log scheduler and http client as soon the url is changed and sync them as it is changed in order ? I would like to avoid re-initialization if url hasn't changed.

Also how could I block the ui thread using http client if the url is being updated when the request was made.

This is a spring application.

Let me know if it is not clear and I'm happy to provide more details.

Comment: Do the objects have to be initialized with the URL? Or can they dynamically get them whenever they need to make a request?  What I mean is instead of storing it as a class variable, could you use a provider or anything?

Comment: Objects have to be initialized right away as soon we know the url is changed. So next time any request/access to the resource would get the data with new url.

Comment: Wait, how many classes are using this URL? Is it just the logger or do you have anything else?

Comment: You have more than a mere synchronization issue, you evidently have an issue of timely updates as well. Perhaps you can clarify this.

Comment: It’s not acceptable to miss the updates. I’m not aware of observable pattern. Quite a few classes.

Comment: @JamesKPolk yes I need to resolve both synchronization issues as well as timely updates. I’m looking for a way when the url is changed, the classes that uses url knows about it right away. Sorry this is my first attempt into writing such kind of code.

Comment: @user2683814 What about something like this: https://i.imgur.com/PWsXx2G.png

Comment: It ensures anything that needs to use the client always gets the correct one after a URL change without wasting any extra time. The only synchronization required is in HTTPClientWrapper

Comment: My apologies, I'm still unsure of where the URL change originates.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I think (cit. needed) he has thread checking every 30 min. for a new URL

Comment: @JamesKPolk We have a external service in our case consul which has new url whenever it changes. We query consul every 30 minutes to get the url and compare with the url we have in the urlschedular and if it is different then perform reinitialization.

Comment: @MatthewKerian: Then the thread which is responsible for getting the new URL can offer a getCurrentURL method that is synchronized on the URL itself. That way callers need not know about any global lock objects. Either that or the observer pattern, perhaps using [this surprisingly detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21004954/238704).

Comment: @JamesKPolk That's a solid example. A little weird that the answer is in java when the question was in C++ though haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with limited information, if anything wouldn't work let me know and I'll change it.

To me the simplest thing is to decouple the HTTPClient from anything that may need it. Decoupling the client means you don't need to deal with synchronization issues in classes that are focused on other things(e.g. logging or pinging the service)

Here's a diagram. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxpvG.png

It seems like you'd be changing very little. The main differences is you'd create a wrapper for your HTTPClient, that way in the client you could synchronize it to make sure the HTTPClient is always the correct one.

An example wrapper, don't use this as it's very simple

```
public class HTTPClientProxy{

    private final Object syncLock = new Object();

    private HTTPClient client;

    public HTTPClient getClient(){
        synchronized(syncLock){
            return client;
        }
    }

    public void updateClient(URL url){
        synchronized(syncLock){
            client = new HTTPClient(url);
        }
    }
}
```

One potential issue, and one that I'm not sure about. Is if you have multiple services, and they all are bundler (e.g. are linked and need to use the same URL). Then you'll need to have something else on that side, so you can ensure they all use the same client. However this would be a good start as it stops you from worrying about getting bad data from the HTTPClient and moves that functionality into the proxy class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the observer pattern is useful here.

The URL scheduler, or whatever class is responsible for the knowing the state of the URL at any given point (called the subject), would maintain a list of `observers` (the other objects which wish to be notified when the URL changes), being the log scheduler and the other http client.

The observers simply implement an interface providing a notification function which accepts the new URL as a parameter. Whenever the url changes, the subject notifies everyone in its list of observers by calling their notification functions.

This makes it so that the log scheduler and other http client are only notified when the URL changes, and they are notified immediately.

If you wished to decouple the observers and subjects (generally more useful when there are many observers observing many subjects), you could build an event manager using a mediator pattern. However, this would probably be overkill given your requirements.

Comment: Thank you. How would be go about something like this in spring application ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Spring application or not, it's built on Java, and this is a software pattern that can be implemented in Java. Simply make your classes which require notifications implement an `observer` interface which provides a function for notifications, and make your state class hold a list of those observers. Perhaps have the observers register themselves with the subject (add themselves to the observer list). Whenever the url changes, loop over that list and call each notification function.